# Im trying to pass array as arguments to httpservice call, but the argumments is evaluating to empty array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs-observables, devextreme-angular

Im trying to upload multiple images, hence converting the image to a base64 encoded string and also storing its metadata with an array.We store the reference to the image path to database hence functionionality is written in  backend for insertion.

However ,

1. To process image files into base64 and store metadata i use array and trying to pass as arguments to a function but i receive empty array in service call. Could someone help me understand why and how to fix this.
2. the upload image is called for every iteration of for loop , WHY?

Thanks in advance .

```js
export class ItemsDetailsComponent {
  //image variables
  itemImageDetails: any = [];
  ItemImageURLs: any = [];
  itemImageCount: number = 0;
  base64image: any = [];
  CustImageData: any;
  itemImageData: any;
  itemimagePath: any;
  fileList: any = [];
  newImageMetaData: any = [];
  imageMetaData: any = [];
  addImagePopupVisible: boolean = false;
  deleteImagePopupVisible: boolean = false;
  tempImageCount: number = 0;
  deleteImageURL: any;
  deleteImageName: any;
  deleteImageConfirmPopUp: boolean;
  value: any[] = [];


  constructor() {
    // ...
  }

  processFile() {
    let count = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.value.length;
      (i++, count++)) {
      this.fileList.push(this.value[count]);
      this.httpDataService.getBase64(this.value[count])
        .then(base64img => {
          this.base64image[this.tempImageCount] = base64img;
          this.base64image[this.tempImageCount] = this.base64image[this.tempImageCount].split(",")[1];
          this.tempImageCount++;

          this.newImageMetaData.push({
            "type": this.fileList[i].type,
            "name": this.fileList[i].name,
            "size": this.fileList[i].size
          });

        });
    }
//want to call this function only after for loop is complete but is getting called at every iteration , WHY?
    this.uploadImages(); 
  }
  


uploadImages() {
  if (this.newImageMetaData.length == this.base64image.length) {
    //recieves expected output(the array in log) **

    console.log(this.newImageMetaData);
    console.log(this.base64image); **

     // below service call is receiving empty array - >> [] for ** [...this.base64image] ** ** [...this.newImageMetaData] **

    this.httpDataService.uploadMultipleImages(["", this.itemCode, [...this.base64image],
        [...this.newImageMetaData]
      ])
      .subscribe(status => {
        if ((status != -1) && status) {
          this.toastr.success(status + "Image(s) Successfully Uploaded");
          this.getImag();
          this.getItemImageDetails();
          this.newImageMetaData = [];
          this.base64image = [];
        } else {
          this.toastr.error("Error Uploading image" + status + " Image(s) Uploaded ");
        }

        this.addImagePopupVisible = false;
      });
  }

}

//
```

```html
<div class="widget-container">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dx-file-uploader #fileUploader [multiple]="true" accept="image/*" [(value)]="value" uploadMode="useForm"></dx-file-uploader>
    <div class="content">
      <div *ngIf="value.length > 0">
        <h4>Selected Files</h4>
      </div>
      <div *ngFor="let file of value">
        <div class="selected-item">
          Name:
          <span>{{file.name}}</span><br /> Size:
          <span>{{file.size}}</span>bytes<br /> Type:
          <span>{{file.type}}</span><br /> Last Modified Date:
          <span>{{file.lastModifiedDate}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <dx-button text="Create Product" type="submit" (onClick)="uploadImages()">
    </dx-button>
  </form>

</div>
<div class="options">
  <div class="caption">Options</div>
  <div class="option">
    <dx-check-box text="Allow multiple files selection" [(value)]="fileUploader.multiple"></dx-check-box>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like your call to `this.uploadImages();` is outside the `processFile()` function.

Comment: You shouldn't be using lastModifiedDate anymore

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming that dx-button is a Call To Action, try and remove the action="uploadImages()" from the form tag, eventually, it will be called once processFile() completes the iteration.
- If you keep an action as well as the submit button inside a form the button click will get performed.

OR

- Remove onClick from button and replace uploadImages() with processFile() in form tag.

Comment: I removed the action in the form and on button cick i added the call to process file but it didnt help to get successful insertion of image , 
Main issue is the array  passed as argument is having length 0 for base64image and newmetadata array variables.